# Community outreach to Salesforce tags in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I've noticed a lot of people are still(newer people) using the Stack Overflow site to ask salesforce questions and often times they go unanswered. Is there anything that can be done to make this exchange the go to place for Salesforce related questions? Perhaps update the wiki in Stackoverflow?

I've [posted a feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382979/make-tags-that-have-associated-stack-exchange-sites-more-obvious) in the Stack Overflow meta that is gaining some traction, but not too much, related to this.

Comment: Having that tag on SO is valid. Some questions (about external servers, php, heroku, maybe a few others) are better asked not as "salesforce" specific questions, but as a programming question which happens to involve salesforce. I do agree with your proposal to show links to the child sites of these tags in their wiki/search pages. Seems like a win/win for both the company behind the stack & the users of the stack.